# Oracle Instant Client not working C#

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle10g, system.data.oracleclient

I'm having trouble installing the oracle instant client, it won't work even though i followed the directions here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-100365.html

Here is my PATH variable http://prntscr.com/3yzql4 , as you can see the PATH has the value of a directory where instant client is located.

However, when i start a project (that uses fluent nhibernate) i get the following exception

```
InnerException {"System.Data.OracleClient requires Oracle client software version 8.1.7 or greater."}
```

at this line in code

```
        return Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(cfg)
            .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<ZAPOSLENIMAPIRANJE>())
            //.ExposeConfiguration(BuildSchema)
            .BuildSessionFactory();
```

I know that people are saying that ODP.NET is better, but this is for a college project and i must use this.

Comment: ODP.net isn't simply "better."  System.Data.OracleClient was marginally functional, and it has been depricated since .NET 3.0.  Curious why you MUST use it.  That's a strange requirement to place on an academic assignment.

Answer (score 0):

The exception says you need version 8.1.7 of the Oracle client.  This is a *very* old version, that is no longer available for download, and has not been, for years.

I think you need to update your entire toolchain, to something that supports at least Oracle 11gR2, if not Oracle 12cR1.

I know you said this was for a class project, so I recommend you talk to the instructor, and ask where he suggests you get Oracle 8.1.7 client software.  (Hint:  The only official source is Oracle Corp., but only if you have a support contract and request it.)